# How to change library type image to pdf in wp.editor

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, pdf, attachment

I am using custom wp.editor for custom post type in wp editor I just want to upload only PDFs. But now my uploader can upload any type of file but it not shows me pdf in the upload media library list.

I search alot but nothing get any helpfull. Here is my code.

**media-uploader.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // Instantiates the variable that holds the media library frame.
    var meta_image_frame;

    // Runs when the image button is clicked.
    $('#wm_issue_pdf_btn').click(function(e){

        // Prevents the default action from occuring.
        e.preventDefault();

        // If the frame already exists, re-open it.
        if ( meta_image_frame ) {
            meta_image_frame.open();
            return;
        }

        // Sets up the media library frame
        meta_image_frame = wp.media.frames.meta_image_frame = wp.media({
            title: meta_image.title,
            button: { text:  meta_image.button },
            library: { type: 'image' }
        });

        // Runs when an image is selected.
        meta_image_frame.on('select', function(){

            // Grabs the attachment selection and creates a JSON representation of the model.
            var media_attachment = meta_image_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

            // Sends the attachment URL to our custom image input field.
            $('#wm_txt_issue_pdf').val(media_attachment.url);
        });

        // Opens the media library frame.
        meta_image_frame.open();
    });

});
```

**functions.php**

```
function wm_image_uploader_enqueue() {
    global $typenow;
    if( ($typenow == 'digital_archives') ) {
        wp_enqueue_media();

        wp_register_script( 'meta-image', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/media-uploader.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
        wp_localize_script( 'meta-image', 'meta_image',
            array(
                'title' => 'Upload a PDF',
                'button' => 'Use this PDF',
            )
        );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'meta-image' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wm_image_uploader_enqueue' );
```

**And metafield code**

```
<input type="text" name="wm_txt_issue_pdf" id="wm_txt_issue_pdf" value="<?php echo $wm_txt_issue_pdf; ?>" style="width: 77%">
<input type="button" id="wm_issue_pdf_btn" class="button" value="Upload a PDF" />
```

Please guide me how can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
function modify_file_types( $file_types ) {

    $file_types['application/pdf'] = array( __( 'PDFs' ), __( 'Manage PDFs' ), _n_noop( 'PDF <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'PDFs <span class="count">(%s)</span>' ) );

    return $file_types;

}

add_filter( 'post_mime_types', 'modify_file_types' );
```

This is to do the upload on custom post types only:

```
function wm_image_uploader_enqueue() {
    global $typenow;
    if( is_singular( 'digital_archives' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_media();

        wp_register_script( 'meta-image', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/media-uploader.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
        wp_localize_script( 'meta-image', 'meta_image',
            array(
                'title' => 'Upload a PDF',
                'button' => 'Use this PDF',
            )
        );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'meta-image' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wm_image_uploader_enqueue' );
```

Comment: can i restrict it only for my digital_archive custom post type

Comment: Restrict the upload or list view?

Comment: Restrict the upload for only custom post type